# How to check if a string contains a substring in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to find whether a substring is in a string. In Python, this involves the `in` operator, so I wrote this code:

```
let a = "abcd";
if "bc" in a {
    do_something();
}
```

I get a strange error message:

```
error: expected `{`, found `in`
 --> src/main.rs:3:13
  |
3 |       if "bc" in a {
  |  _____________-^
4 | |         do_something();
5 | |     }
  | |_____- help: try placing this code inside a block: `{ a <- { do_something(); }; }`
```

The message suggests that I put it in a block, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Rust has no such operator. You can use the [`String::contains` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.contains) instead:

```
if a.contains("bc") {
    do_something();
}
```

Comment: What if I want to see if a string contains, say, one more more capital letters?

Comment: You should probably post that as a separate question. Personally, I'd try to use regex for that.

Comment: For anyone else who comes to this.  you can do `thing.contains(['A', 'B', 'C])` to check if `thing` has capitalized A, B, or C in it.

Comment: how do i also get the index?

Comment: If you check the docs, there is a [`String::find` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.find) that returns the index for characters or fuller string patterns